# animated node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes

I got a simple Ti*k*Z nodes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=6mm, row sep=5mm]{
    \node (DT) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<2->]{Source de données}; \\
    \node (IF) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<3->] {Items fréquents}; \\
    \node (FER) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<4->] {Fermetures}; \\
    \node (SUB) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<5->] {Sous-ensembles des fermetures}; \\
    \node (ISC) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<6->] {Itemsets cycliques}; \\
    \node (RAC) [draw,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,visible on=<7->] {Régles d'association cycliques}; \\
};
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<3->] (DT) -- (IF);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (IF) -- (FER);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<5->] (FER) -- (SUB);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<6->] (SUB) -- (ISC);
    \draw[->, thick,visible on=<7->] (ISC) -- (RAC);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I just need to make a label on the right side for each node that appears when the node appears (not before or after).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can pass a style to all nodes inside a `\matrix` by giving the option `nodes={style}` avoiding over crowded drawings. You can also make style keys that concatenate several keys into one with `my key/.style={keys}` [see this question for instance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Comment: Have you tried putting nodes on the second column of the matrix and making they appear with the nodes beside them, as if they were labels?

Comment: Can you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.